# Snowflake dynamic case statement

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column in table A which returns screen_view,screen_tracking_view. This is configurable. So some more values can be added in the list.
In table B, I want to generate a column IS_EVENT_EXCLUDE which maps existing HITS_EVENT_ACTION column with above generate list. I can write the below code to achieve the expected output. But I want this to be dynamic. If there is new values included in the list. It should query from the table A & dynamically include this in this statement or any other possible method to generate the expected output of table B. FYI, I am writing all this SP.

```
CASE WHEN HITS_EVENT_ACTION='screen_view' THEN 1 
WHEN HITS_EVENT_ACTION='screen_tracking_view' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IS_EVENT_EXCLUDE
```

[expectedoutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APXnN.png)

Comment: Please don't link to images, provide all the required information in the question, preferably as editable text. Please provide sample data and the result you want to achieve based on this data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use a look up table and a left join? You add new values to TABLE_A and you will get the correct results:

```
create table TABLE_A (events varchar);
insert into TABLE_A values ('screen_view'),('screenview'),('screen_tracking_view');  
  
create table TABLE_B (id number, HITS_EVENT_ACTION varchar);
insert into TABLE_B values (1,'screen_view'),
(2,'screen_view'),
(3,'screenview'),
(4,'drawerevet'),
(5,'user_engagement'),
(6,'unloadcontent'),
(7,'screenview'),
(8,'innttelemetry'),
(9,'screen_view');
  
select HITS_EVENT_ACTION, IFF( TABLE_A.events IS NULL, 0, 1 ) IS_EVENT_EXCLUDE
from TABLE_B left join TABLE_A on TABLE_B.HITS_EVENT_ACTION = TABLE_A.events ;

+-------------------+------------------+
| HITS_EVENT_ACTION | IS_EVENT_EXCLUDE |
+-------------------+------------------+
| screen_view       |                1 |
| screen_view       |                1 |
| screenview        |                1 |
| drawerevet        |                0 |
| user_engagement   |                0 |
| unloadcontent     |                0 |
| screenview        |                1 |
| innttelemetry     |                0 |
| screen_view       |                1 |
+-------------------+------------------+
```